# Python Problem Json return value is overwrite the values before

Tags: python, json, list, overwrite

```
Json_example = {'id' : ""}

def getNumber(a_number):
    Json_example['id'] = a_number
    return Json_example

liste = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
ergebnis = []
for i in liste:
    print(i)
    result = getNumber(i)
    ergebnis.append(result)
print(ergebnis)
```

the output is:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
[{'id': 6}, {'id': 6}, {'id': 6}, {'id': 6}, {'id': 6}, {'id': 6}]
```

is like the output like this:

```
[{'id': 1}, {'id': 2}, {'id': 3}, {'id': 4}, {'id': 5}, {'id': 6}]
```

I request for a list of numbers a get a Json back for every numbers
But the request overwrite the values from before.
What can i do?

Comment: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 2):

As your using only one unique instance of `dict` : `Json_example = {'id': ""}`, you keep updating and saving it in the list.

You need to save a copy each time, here's some ways

```
# Create a dict each time
def getNumber(a_number):
    return {'id': a_number}


# Update the one dict, then create a copy of it
Json_example = {'id': ""}
def getNumber(a_number):
    Json_example['id'] = a_number
    return {**Json_example}
```